# UIViewController Won't Unload

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have been researching this question almost since I started learning to program for iOS (February 2012). I have read lots of posts on here which seem to be asking the same question and I have tried to implement the answers into my application to no avail. I am sure I am missing something simple.

I have a view switching test application. There are three views: orange, blue, yellow. It starts out on the orange view with two buttons - switch to blue view and switch to yellow view. When I click on switch to yellow view - the views revolve against a white background. The yellow view also has two buttons - switch to orange view and switch to blue view. When I click on switch to orange view the view flips back but instead of a white background the orange view is the background. How do I make that orange view not be there?

This is the code that I use to do the transition:

```
-(IBAction)switchToYellowView:(id)sender {

YellowViewController *myViewController = [[YellowViewController alloc]
                                         initWithNibName:@"YellowViewController"
                                         bundle:nil];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

From what I have read, I thought I needed to remove the orange view from the superview. But when I use

```
[OrangeViewController.view removeFromSuperView]
```

I get an error saying that "property view is not found on object OrangeViewController."

And if I switch from the yellow view to the blue view the orange view is still in the background. And then switching back to orange from blue, yellow is still in the background.

I read somewhere else, that I need to release these views also by adding

```
[myViewController release]
```

after I commit the animations. I thought that this was unnecessary when using ARC (which I am using). And when I do this, trying to go back to the orange view causes a Bad Access crash.

Perhaps I need to do something with rootViewController? I did set the OrangeView as a subview of "window" in the app delegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:viewController2.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

viewController2 is a pointer to the OrangeViewController.

Because of the first comment, I started to look around for switching out rootViewController - and found Ken Anderson's lecture notes about switching the rootviewcontroller programatically. I can get the yellow to change in, but it isn't animating.

The next two comments are leading me in other directions - might the best thing be to use a containercontroller - like UITabBarController? Except use my own buttons and never display a tab bar?

I can, of course, provide the entire application for perusal. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
[self transitionFromViewController:currentViewController toViewController:firstViewNav duration: options: animations:^{
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        }];
```

Comment: +1:  The main problem with the original code is that he is never transitioning from one view to another, but instead is adding the new view as a subview of the existing view.

Comment: Jason - not sure how to use the code snippet - and I am not sure it will work since OrangeViewController is currently the rootViewController and is the parent controller from my understanding of things.

Comment: Inafziger - The code I was using I have seen in various examples around the web and seems to work to transition between the two views. What is doesn't do is allow me to somehow disappear the first view until it is actually needed again. Which is what I would like to happen.

Comment: From what I've seen in your code, you used [self.view addSubview:myViewController.view]; to add the view, but myViewController wasn't added, so when you are trying to do something that declared in myViewController, I think your app will crash. If you are trying to add myViewController in the rootViewController, you can use [rootViewController addChildViewController:myViewController], then use [self.view addSubView:myViewController.view], with transition. Hopefully this can help.

Comment: Thank you Jasno, but I am not following  - the code as shown works fine and no crashes - it just doesn't eliminate the OrangeViewController so that when I flip back, instead of seeing a white screen in the background, I see the OrangeViewController just sitting there...

Answer (score 0):

Inside switchToYellowView:, you are adding the yellow view as a subview of your current view, which is the orange view. Thus if you try to remove the orange view with [OrangeViewController.view removeFromSuperView] (which probably isn't working because view isn't a public property of OrangeViewController), then you would be removing the orange view which has the yellow view as a subview, effectively removing both from the window. I think what you want to do inside switchToYellowView is something like this:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview]; //remove the orange view
[window addSubview:myViewController.view]; //replace it with the yellow view
```

Comment: To what does "window" refer? When I put this code in, window is an undeclared identifier.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work - the screen went blank. Thank you for the thought, though!

Comment: Instead of `[window addSubview:myView]` try `[self.view.superview addSubview:myView]` at least if `self` is a `UIViewController`. Besides, I would implement the switching of views in your root view controller. Work with delegates to make the coloured views inform the root view controller that it wants to change.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea - I will try it - I don't know what my root view controller is, though...